# mediawiki wiki documentation which helps Debian

Tags: debian, mediawiki

Does anybody know which project wiki is that which uses mediawiki and many a times is useful for Debian users ? It is a debian derivative but I'm not remembering either the link or project name. Debian uses moinmoin wiki while the other project uses mediawiki and more often than not is up-to-date as mediawiki offers sectional edits which moinmoin lacks.

Comment: could you make your comment into answer, it seems to be Arch . I saw the list too but icouldn't think of any in the first instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a derivative of Debian, but [Arch's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) has information I've often found useful, presented with the right amount of detail for me to solve my problems.

If that's not it, Debian's wiki includes a [list of its own derivatives](https://wiki.debian.org/Derivatives).